# Why Liveness / Readiness probe failed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy an app to Kubernetes cluster via Helm charts. Every time I try to deploy the app I get

> "Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.7:80/: dial tcp
>   172.17.0.7:80: connect: connection refused" and "Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.7:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.7:80: connect:
>   connection refused"

.

This is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "mychart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "mychart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- include "mychart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: nikovlyubomir/docker-spring-boot:latest
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 200
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 200
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

I read that possible solution might be adding more initialDelaySecond in both probes, but still this did not resolve my issue.

Any opinion?

Comment: Do the probes keep failing or do they switch to green eventually? Is the application properly started? What do the logs say?

Comment: The probes keep failing, whenever I deploy the app, I see the deployment green for like 1-2 min, but after some time (maybe the delay) it turns back to red. 
I think the app is properly started, those are my events:
1) Successfully assigned default/examplee-mychart-67f9c7c485-47zw8 to minikube
2)Container image "nikovlyubomir/docker-spring-boot:latest" already present on machine
3)Created container mychart

Comment: 4) Started container mychart

Comment: 5) Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.7:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.7:80: connect: connection refused
6) Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.7:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.7:80: connect: connection refused
7 ) Container mychart failed liveness probe, will be restarted
8 ) Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: Is the app actually running on port 80? Often, the default port is 8080. Please check the logs of the pod. The application should state whether is has started successfully or terminated due to an error.

Comment: 2020-03-07 13:01:46.150  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.example.Exercise.ExerciseApplication   : Started ExerciseApplication in 2.904 seconds (JVM running for 3.556)
2020-03-07 13:05:22.318  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Comment: It looks it started successfully, when check the pods by typing "kubectl get pods" I see that the status is "CrashLoopBackOff"

Comment: Have you checked the port? For testing, you can comment the probes and see if the pod comes up then. At least then you know whether the probse are at the core of the problem.

Comment: I changed the ports, they were not the same, now it's all setup and I got another exception : "Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404"

Comment: Then there is nothing to `HttpGet` there.

Comment: What it should be?
 livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 200
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 1993
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 200
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 1993

Comment: An endpoint that does exists. A 404 error (also known as "Not Found") indicates that there is no matching resource/endpoint.

Comment: add spring boot actuator in the pom dependency and change path to /actuator/health

Answer (score 3):

Since I can pull the image  I did a try

```
$ docker run -d nikovlyubomir/docker-spring-boot:latest
9ac42a1228a610ae424217f9a2b93cabfe1d3141fe49e0665cc71cb8b2e3e0fd
```

I got logs

```
$ docker logs 9ac
...
2020-03-08 02:02:30.552  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 1993 (http) with context path ''
```

Seems the application starts on port 1993, not 80

then I check the port and connection in container:

```
$ docker exec -ti 9ac bash
root@9ac42a1228a6:/# curl localhost:1993
{"timestamp":"2020-03-08T02:03:12.104+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
root@9ac42a1228a6:/# curl localhost:1993/actuator/health
{"timestamp":"2020-03-08T02:04:01.348+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/actuator/health"}
root@9ac42a1228a6:/# curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
root@9ac42a1228a6:/# curl localhost:80/actuator/health
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

So make sure the check path `/` or other is properly set and the port `80` or `1993` is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused means the container is not listening on port 80. Also when you setup a http readiness probe or liveness probe as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

To perform a probe, the kubelet sends an HTTP GET request to the server that is running in the Container and listening on port 80. If the handler for the server’s `/` path returns a success code, the kubelet considers the Container to be alive and healthy. If the handler returns a failure code, the kubelet kills the Container and restarts it.

**So you do not have a handler in your code which returns success code for path `/`. Since it's a spring boot app , assuming you have spring boot actuator dependency in pom you can change the path to `/actuator/health` which should solve the issue.**