# Troubleshooting k8s readiness probe failure

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, django-rest-framework, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run my django rest framework application in k8s environment but readiness probe fails. I wonder how to get what is wrong.
When I look at pod logs the app seems to be running. It has unapplied migrations, but it is ok:

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl logs test-bbdccbc76-8cwg9
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Server initialized for gevent.
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/app/staticfiles' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
December 27, 2022 - 06:13:28
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Here is `describe pod` output:

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl describe pod test-bbdccbc76-8cwg9
Name:                 test-bbdccbc76-8cwg9
Namespace:            test
Priority:             2000
Priority Class Name:  default
Service Account:      default
Node:                 sd2-k8s-stg-n05/10.216.14.52
Start Time:           Tue, 27 Dec 2022 11:11:14 +0500
Labels:               app=test
                      pod-template-hash=bbdccbc76
Annotations:          checksum/config: f0ee0887d3fd078979831f04d13ade8759ef8a4ee9aad23830c5909300e322b4
                      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: ac4c0c57c0a3baa1c15a78aedb36e3e1890f8b9859547807b1e3587835792efb
                      cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.233.110.84/32
                      cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.233.110.84/32
                      container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/test: runtime/default
                      kubernetes.io/psp: restricted
                      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.233.110.84
IPs:
  IP:           10.233.110.84
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/test-bbdccbc76
Containers:
  test:
    Container ID:  containerd://26e3234ba31c09d6d62e3efb999634cb64d26d6ce2e8e734a26104d62b6f2f5f
    Image:         registry/library/test:latest
    Image ID:      registry/library/test-@sha256:12345678b16eb2c90324916756846d5dfa557198bd4aeed9e790db677702b1
    Port:          8000/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      python
      manage.py
      runserver
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 27 Dec 2022 11:11:15 +0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  500Mi
      memory:             500Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  500Mi
      memory:             500M
    Liveness:             http-get http://:8000/healthz delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:            http-get http://:8000/healthz delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      test-configmap  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      CONNECTION_STRING:     mongodb://xxx:yyy@zzz:27017
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-tpstr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-tpstr:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  79s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned test/test-bbdccbc76-8cwg9 to xx-k8s-xx
  Normal   Pulling    78s                kubelet            Pulling image "registry/library/test:latest"
  Normal   Pulled     78s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry/library/test:latest" in 57.066835ms
  Normal   Created    78s                kubelet            Created container test
  Normal   Started    78s                kubelet            Started container test
  Warning  Unhealthy  29s (x2 over 39s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.233.110.84:8000/healthz": dial tcp 10.233.110.84:8000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  29s (x2 over 39s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.233.110.84:8000/healthz": dial tcp 10.233.110.84:8000: connect: connection refused
```

Here's service:

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl describe service test-service
Name:                     test-service
Namespace:                test
Labels:                   app=test
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.1.0
                          helm.sh/chart=my-helm-char-1.0.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
Selector:                 app=test
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.233.53.185
IPs:                      10.233.53.185
Port:                     api-port  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               api-port/TCP
NodePort:                 api-port  32426/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: You seem to have included a lot of diagnostic output, but none of your own source code; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/` line is suspicious to me; does ["The connection was reset" in localhost:8000 using django and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183313/the-connection-was-reset-in-localhost8000-using-django-and-docker) describe your problem?

Comment: enter the pod and try to make http request with the healthcheck url - `http://10.233.110.84:8000/healthz` if you get `connection refused` so your app don't gave this endpoint or don't listen to the localhost (I guess 10.233.110.84 is the pod ip)

Comment: Check this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577625/why-liveness-readiness-probe-failed) may help to resolve your issue.